# how to do i select multiple record from a report

Tags: oracle-apex

I would want to know the coding for the following:

I would like select multiple records from a report which satisfies certain conditions.
I need the code in APEX

Comment: It's really not clear what you mean.

Comment: Is this about Oracle APEX or Salesforce APEX?